# progress bar tint color in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, background, background-color, android-progressbar, custom-renderer

is there any way to change the default tint color using progress bar in xamarin forms . if not how would I create a droid custom renderer for this.
the picture shows a slider but what I am looking for is something similar in a progress bar . 
[image]

Comment: Do you try https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/28894/progressbar-color-in-xamarin-forms

Comment: Did you want to change only background color for progressbar ?

Comment: yes , the inside only  because is blue by default and I need it white. Thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get it right, but if you want to change the ProgressBar background color, you can do it on your pcl project by accessing ProgressBar BackgroundColor property, like this:

```
var progressBar = new ProgressBar
{
    BackgroundColor = Color.White
};
```

But if you want to change progressbar's tintcolor on Android platform, an easy way would be changing styles.xml colorAccent value. As you can check by its comment:

colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated which is used to tint widgets

Comment: yes , indeed. I would like to change the tint in android and ios .Thanks !